# length of string containing \0

Tags: c++, c

```
 char p[]="abc\012\0x34"; 
 printf("%d\n",strlen(p));
```

I am getting output 4. Shouldn't it be 3 ???
Although for following i am getting 3.

```
 char p[]="abc\0"; 
 printf("%d\n",strlen(p));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your string *does* contain four characters before the `\0`, i.e. `abc` *and* `\012`.

The latter is a valid octal escape sequence, which is 10 in decimal, i.e an ASCII linefeed character.

`\0x34` on the other hand isn't valid octal - only the `\0` part is valid hence that's the real end of your NUL terminated string.

Answer (score 4):

`\012` is an octal escaped character, not a `NUL` followed by `1` and `2`. `x` terminates the second octal character so it is genuinely a `NUL`. (`\x34` would be the correct form for a hexadecimal escaped character.)

The representation of a `NUL` character as `\0` is just a special case of an octal escape sequence. In general a `\` can be followed by one, two or three octal digits to form a valid octal escape sequence in a character or string literal.

Answer (score 4):

Your string has length 4:

You code is equivalent to:
    char p[]={'a','b'.'c'.'\012','\0','x','3','4','\0'};

\012 - character with code 12 in octal numeral system (= 10 in decimal = '\n')

Answer (score 1):

`\012` is a single character. It's stopping on the `\0` after that (and `"x34"` is three more characters, not counting the NUL terminator).

Answer (score 0):

`\012` is an octal value("\n").